# rerender rich:dataTable

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am having trouble re-rendering a `rich:dataTable`
My bean has list of strings, when I modify the list I want to re-render the table

I tried

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.add}" reRender="table">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

In the been list I have the element but the `rich:datatable` with the id table doesn't rerender

I am using richfaces 4

Comment: I am guessing you are using jsf 2 since you are using Richfaces 4?

Comment: If RichFaces 4 is used, then it should render=table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put your data table in an *a4j:outputPanel* and re-render the output panel instead:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="tablePanel">
    <rich:dataTable ... >
    ..
    </rich:dataTable>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

OutputPanel must be visible on first page load (*rendered=true*). You can not re-render elements which are not rendered on first page load.